# Why I Can't Use My Method in Another Class? (The Method X is Undefined for the Type Y)

Tags: java, class, methods, error-handling

I wrote a code in Java but I'm keep getting an error named **"The method getMinor(Matrix) is undefined for the type Main."** for the *last line of Main class.*
I can use my other methods in Main class but can't use getMinor and printMinor methods in it. What am I doing wrong?

This is Matrix class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Matrix {

    private int n;
    private int m;
    private ArrayList<Double> Matrices = new ArrayList<Double>();
    
    public Matrix(int n, int m) {
        
        this.n = n;
        this.m = m;
        
        Matrices = new ArrayList<Double>(n*m);
        
    }
    
    public void printElement(int a, int b) {
        
        int index = (a-1)*m + b - 1;
        double element = Matrices.get(index);
        System.out.println(element);
        
    }
    
    public double getElement(int a, int b) {
        
        int index = (a-1)*m + b - 1;
        double element = Matrices.get(index);
        return element;
        
    }
    
    public void printMatrix() {
        
        for(int a = 1; a <= n; a++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int b = 1; b <= m; b++) {
                if(b == 1) {
                    System.out.print(Matrices.get((a-1)*m + b - 1).toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  " +Matrices.get((a-1)*m + b - 1).toString());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        
    }
    
    public int getRowNumber() {
        
        return n;
        
    }
    
    public int getColumnNumber() {
        
        return m;
        
    }
    
    public Matrix getMinor(Matrix Matrices) {
        
        Matrix minor = new Matrix(Matrices.getRowNumber() - 1, Matrices.getColumnNumber() - 1);
        
        for(int r = 1; r <= Matrices.getRowNumber(); r++) {
            for(int i = 1; i < Matrices.getColumnNumber(); i++) {
                minor.addTo(r, i, Matrices.getElement(r+1, i+1));
            }
        }
        
        return minor;
        
    }
    
    public void printMinor(Matrix Matrices) {
        
        Matrix minor = getMinor(Matrices);
        minor.printMatrix();    
        
    }

        public void addTo(int a, int b, double value) {
        
        int index = (a-1)*m + b - 1;
        Matrices.add(index, value);
        
    }
    
}
```

This is Main class:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Matrix myNew2Matrix = new Matrix(3, 3);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(1,1,3);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(1,2,2);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(1,3,2);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(2,1,1);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(2,2,4);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(2,3,4);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(3,1,8);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(3,2,2);
        myNew2Matrix.addTo(3,3,5);
        getMinor(myNew2Matrix); //getting error in this line
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you've posted, `getMinor(...)` is defined as a method of the Matrix class. This means you would need to call `myNew2Matrix.getMinor(myNew2Matrix)` with your current code. If you want to avoid specifying `myNew2Matrix` twice, you could do one of the following.

1. Make `getMinor` a static method (not bound to an instance of Matrix). If you implement it this way, you would call `Matrix.getMinor(myNew2Matrix)`.
2. Don't pass an argument to `getMinor`, instead use `this` as the matrix you're performing calculations on. If you choose to do it this way, you would call `myNew2Matrix.getMinor()`

```java
   public Matrix getMinor() {
        
        Matrix minor = new Matrix(this.getRowNumber() - 1, this.getColumnNumber() - 1);
        
        for(int r = 1; r <= this.getRowNumber(); r++) {
            for(int i = 1; i < this.getColumnNumber(); i++) {
                minor.addTo(r, i, this.getElement(r+1, i+1));
            }
        }
        
        return minor;
    }
```

Because you control the Matrix class, and the only thing you pass to `getMinor` is a `Matrix`, the second option would probably be the better option of the two, but both options will work.

Comment: ```
public void printMinor() {
  
  Matrix minor = this.getMinor();
  minor.printMatrix(); 
  
 }
```
Then should I edit the printMinor like this? I'm asking because when I edit it like this I'm getting an error like "Index X out of bounds for length y."

Comment: That's how you would edit it, yes.